# take facebook page url and store id and slug separately

Tags: php, regex

I'm developing a web app where users enter their facebook page url either in this format: 
`http://www.facebook.com/pages/Graffiti/119622954518`

or
`http://www.facebook.com/thefirkinandfox`

With php - how do I detect which format automatically, then split (explode?) the parts (the slug and the id or just the slug if the second version).

There is sometimes query data at the end of the url when viewing your own facebook page as an administrator, how do I detect and remove that? I think the answer will be regex of some kind - but I've really only used this to make sure an input is email and still didn't understand it that well... thanks in advance.

Possible entires may or may not include http:// at the beginning... I'd like to account for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use one regexp, try this:

```php
$url = 'www.facebook.com/pages/Graffiti/119622954518';
if(preg_match('@^(https?://)?(www\.)?facebook\.com/((pages/([^/]+)/(\d+))|([^/]+))@', $url, $matches)) {
  $slug = isset($matches[5]) ? $matches[5] : (isset($matches[7]) ? $matches[7] : null);
  $id = isset($matches[6]) ? $matches[6] : null;
}
```

Comment: @RReverser, hi thanks that works great with `www.facebook.com/pages/Graffiti/119622954518` and `http://www.facebook.com/pages/Graffiti/119622954518`. Any ideas for detecting if it is input in this format: `http://www.facebook.com/thefirkinandfox`? Thanks

Comment: @Andypandy: I think the else{} part of the IF should be the other format

Comment: @Andypandy: I think if you change the last part in @RReverser answer, it should work for the other URL too. Try changing `|([^/]+)` towards the end of the regex to `|(\w+)`, keeping everything else same.

Comment: @abhay, it doesn't seem to work - should it be matches[5] also if its `http://www.facebook.com/thefirkinandfox` format? thanks

Comment: it works if you do `$slug = isset($matches[3]) ? $matches[3] : ((isset($matches[7]) ? $matches[7] : null));` thanks for the help

Comment: actually i was wrong - but this works:  `$slug = count($matches)==8 ? $matches[3] : $matches[5];`
 ` $id = count($matches)==8 ? null : $matches[6];` thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two parts:

```
^http://www.facebook.com/pages/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(?:\?.*)$
```

If the first one doesn't match, use this:

```
^http://www.facebook.com/([^/]+)(?:\?.*)$
```

The explosion, you mention is the value of the capturing group.

So the code might look something like this:

```
$subject = "my string";
if (preg_match ('#^http://www.facebook.com/pages/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(?:\?.*)$#', $subject))
   print ($groups[1] + ' ' + $groups[1]);
else if (preg_match ('#^http://www.facebook.com/([^/]+)(?:\?.*)$#', $subject))
   print ($groups[1]);
```

Comment: thanks any chance you'd explain that further and some sample code - looks like french. thanks

Comment: @AndyPandy, php is not one of my languages, but this out to be about right.